# Working with AudioPlayer in Java

Tags: java, swing

In my swing application i am using a class to play a sound when the mouse is clicked. The problem i have is when i call the class the sound is played onetime and when suddenly another button is clicked it doesn't play the sound. I tried giving a delay in my code but stilll id doesn't work as i expected. Is it something to do with threads ?? I am not good at threads so please tell me how to do that. The code i am using is as below,

```
package utilities;  
import java.applet.AudioClip;  
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.InputStream;   
import java.net.URL;  
import java.util.logging.Level;  
import java.util.logging.Logger;  
import sun.audio.AudioData;  
import sun.audio.AudioPlayer;  
import sun.audio.AudioStream;  
import sun.audio.ContinuousAudioDataStream;  
public class Tone {`  

    File wavFile = new File("sounds/Windows Default.wav");
    URL urlClick = Tone.class.getResource("/sounds/WindowsDefault.wav");
    AudioClip sound;
    public void sound() {
        AudioStream as = null;
        try {

            InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/sounds/WindowsDefault.wav");
            as = new AudioStream(in);
            AudioData data = as.getData();
// Create ContinuousAudioDataStream.
ContinuousAudioDataStream cas = new ContinuousAudioDataStream (data);
            //System.out.println(as.getLength());
            AudioPlayer.player.start(cas);

            //System.out.println(urlClick);
                //sound = Applet.newAudioClip(urlClick);
        //this.wait(1000);
           for(int i =0;i<100000;i++){
               double k = Math.pow(i, 5);
               if(i==99999){
                   AudioPlayer.player.stop(cas);
                   return;
               }
           }
           // sound.play();
            String relativeDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
            System.out.println(relativeDirectory);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Tone.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                as.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Tone.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
Tone tone = new Tone();
tone.sound();
System.out.println("done");

    }
}
```

--EDIT--
The reason why i used the continuousaudiostream is because the sound was not happening at all when i use this aleast hear some sound. Even when i used AudioStream the problem was there..

Comment: Use `javax.sound.sampled.Clip` or directly an `AudioInputStream` instead of delving into `sun.*` classes.

Comment: when you call the method directly (outside of your applet) can you get the sound to play two times?

Comment: no even when i call the method directly i cant hear the sound sometimes.. when i say directly i am calling from main()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Better not use hidden classes/api - as you already have read in the link you got in your other question :-)

2) stop/close an already running sound before starting/re-open again, in public api something like:

```
Clip clip;

private void doPlay(final String url) {
    try {
        stopPlay();
        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem
                .getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream(url));
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(inputStream);
        clip.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        stopPlay();
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void stopPlay() {
    if (clip != null) {
        clip.stop();
        clip.close();
        clip = null;
    }
}
```

(Note: completely closed for illustration only, refine the logic to load once and then stop/start again)

Comment: i dont want to stop and start. i just want to play a click sound not more than a second really. so for every click i want to play that once. is there anythign like once the sound is started when a click event is generated the next click event will not call the sound() method again to play the .wav file ?? i dont think so.. explain me if i was wrong..

Comment: @Deepak:  "i just want to play a click sound not more than a second really."  Look into `Clip.isRunning()`, `Clip.isActive()`, `LineListener`, and `javax.swing.Timer`.  You are bound to find an answer using some combination of those.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the ContinuousAudioDataStream only resets after the end of the file was reached, so it could be that the second button click happened before this occurred.  Maybe try resetting the stream