# What can I use instead of AudioPlayer.player.stop();?

Tags: java, swing, audio, javasound

I have successfully coded playing audio in my GUI.

**But when I use :**

```
AudioPlayer.player.stop();
```

The word `"`stop`"` is crossed out and a warning is given saying "Methods `stop(), suspend() and resume()` of `java.lang.Thread` are dangerous and should not be used." I am using Netbeans `IDE 6.9.1`

All the website's I've read have no problem using this method. Is there another way of stopping the audio being played?

**Here is my code :**

```
String song = songList.getSelectedValue().toString();//determines the string of the selected value in the list box
    if(song.equals("Matt Nathanson - Come On Get Higher")){//if this song is selected...
        InputStream in;
        try{
        in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Stuff\\Grade Twelve\\Computer Programming\\Unit 4\\Step 3\\GuitarForBeginners\\src\\guitarforbeginners\\resources\\Come On Get Higher.wav"));
        AudioStream audio = new AudioStream(in);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audio);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        if (cancelButton.isSelected()){
            AudioPlayer.player.stop(audio);
        }
    }
```

(In reply to greg-449)

Used the link you suggested as well as http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/__/co/CoreJavaSound.java.html. The program runs but prints `null`. Ideas?? Thanks..

```
if (song.equals("Matt Nathanson - Come On Get Higher")){//if this song is selected...
        try{
            stopPlay();
            AudioInputStream audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("C:\\Stuff\\Grade Twelve\\Computer Programming\\Unit 4\\Step 3\\GuitarForBeginners\\src\\guitarforbeginners\\resources\\Come On Get Higher.wav"));
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audio);
            clip.start();
        } catch(Exception e){
            stopPlay();
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
    }
```

Comment: You should not use `sun.*` classes - see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804811/working-with-audioplayer-in-java) for alternatives.

Comment: thank you, please see revised code

Comment: Note the revised code has completely changed the question!  As such, this q. should be finalized and a new question started.

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
    String song = songList.getSelectedValue().toString();//determines the string of the selected value in the list box
        if(song.equals("Matt Nathanson - Come On Get Higher")){//if this song is selected...
            InputStream in;
            InputStream closetrick;
            try{
            in = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Stuff\\Grade Twelve\\Computer Programming\\Unit 4\\Step 3\\GuitarForBeginners\\src\\guitarforbeginners\\resources\\Come On Get Higher.wav"));
 closetrick =new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Stuff\\Grade Twelve\\Computer Programming\\Unit 4\\Step 3\\GuitarForBeginners\\src\\guitarforbeginners\\resources\\Zerosec.wav"));
            AudioStream audio = new AudioStream(in);
            AudioPlayer.player.start(audio);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("File not found");
            }
            if (cancelButton.isSelected()){
                 AudioStream audio2 = new AudioStream(closetrick);
            AudioPlayer.player.start(audio2);
            }
        }
```

where Zerosec wav is wav with lenth of zero sec

Comment: This does not work because Audio Player just plays each song selected overtop one another without stopping the previous one played. The zero second wav file does play, but you cant hear it overtop of the other song still playing

Comment: I'm surprised that this works. Often audio files cause "Mark/Reset" errors when they become InputStreams. Usually it is best to avoid InputStream and load the file or url directly into an AudioInputStream. Secondly, if you have a file that is playing, you should be able to stop it manually yourself before launching a new instance. I don't generally use AudioPlayer, though. I tend to stick with Clip and SourceDataLines. So my advice may not pertain.

Answer (score 0):

```
**
```

you should intilaize an AudioPlayer object and then you call his methods.

**